# prove that a group, G, of infinite order has infinitely many distinct subgroups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

How would I go about proving the following statement?:

Suppose $G$ is a group with |$G$| = $\infty$. Prove that $G$ has infinitely many $\underline{distinct}$ subgroups.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: How could a group have infinitely many subgroups and not have infinitely many *distinct* subgroups?

Comment: The 'distinct' thing is indeed funny.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finite number of subgroups $\Rightarrow$  finite group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22996/finite-number-of-subgroups-rightarrow-finite-group)

Comment: Did the source previously define _distinct_ to mean something in particular? If not, the usual meaning is just $H_1 \neq H_2$, and you wouldn't normally bother to specify that, since it's implied by counting. But if for example _distinct_ actually means $H_1 \cap H_2 = \{e\}$ for all pairs of chosen subgroups, the statement is still true and a bit more interesting.

Comment: I tried to use the contrapositive of the question: "if G has finite subgroups, the the order of G is finite." But I don't know how to actually prove it.

Answer (score 10):

There are two cases:

1. There is $g \in G$ such that $\lvert g \rvert = \infty$. Then $\langle g \rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ which has infinitely many distinct subgroups.
2. Every $g \in G$ has finite order $\lvert g \rvert < \infty$. Pick $g_0 \in G$ and define (recursively) $g_n$ to be any element of $G$ such that $g_n \notin \langle g_0 \rangle \cup \dotsb \cup \langle g_{n-1} \rangle$. Since the set on the right is always finite (being a finite union of finite sets) then there is always such $g_n$ because $G$ is infinite. It follows that $\langle g_n \rangle$ give us infinitely many distinct subgroups of $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: If $G$ has finitely many [distinct] subgroups, then it has finitely many [distinct] cyclic subgroups.

Hint 2: If $G$ has finitely many [distinct] subgroups, then all its cyclic subgroups must have finite order.

Hint 3: Combining the above two hints with the fact that each element of $G$ lies in a cyclic subgroup yields $|G| < \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

1. Show that the infinite cyclic group has infinitely many distinct subgroups.
2. Let $g_1$ be any non-unit element of $G$. If $G_1 = \langle g\rangle$ is infinite, we're done. If not, choose any $g_2$ in the set $G\backslash G_1$, and so on.